# url rewrite proxy pass

Tags: url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

This is to do with domains and URL mapping ...etc.  I tried with apache and reverse proxy, rewrite, can't get it to work so far.

#### Scenario.

Target Customer owns domain www.customer.com , wants his users to use the site using URLs like
`www.customer.com/a/b/c?blah`

We have implemented the software for him and runs on one of our ec2 box, with IP xyz, with a domain 
yoyoyyo.provider.com  => yoyoyo being a subdomain of provider.com.

So, for the customer, I helped him and added a A record for www.customer.com which maps it to yoyoyo.provider.com

So us, I have added a A record for yoyoyo.provider.com => ec2's ip address xyz.

So far so good.

Ultimately, to invoke the software, essentially it is

`http://yoyoyo.provider.com/customer/software/service   "+"   /a/b/c?blah`  => the full URL

#### now, the logic and flow i assumed is this

1. user types in browser www.customer.com/a/b/c?blah
2. dns looks up www.customer.com, and maps it to yoyoyo.provider.com
3. url becomes yoyoyo.provider.com/a/b/c?blah
4. dns looks up yoyoyo.provider.com => ip address xyz
5. url becomes xyz/a/b/c?blah
6. now the call comes to the actual box, finds the apache server

in apache, i thought i can do it as a proxy pass , or a rewrite rule , which essentially comes down to
map/rewrite (pseudo code as below)

^/.*  => http://yoyoyo.provider.com/customer/software/service/$1  ;; where $1 evals to be a/b/c?blah

1. the software gets called.

But of course, it is not working !  The browser gets a blank page
Any ideas ?